# Intrinsic thought of relative topology

Tags: general-topology

I am learning topology and I found some difficulties in relative topology of $\mathbb R^2$ usual space.

For example, let $Y=\{x:d(x,<0,0>)=1\}\setminus\{<1,0>\}$ where $d$ is the distance and the topology is the relativized usual topology. Geometrically, $Y$ is a unit circle without the point at $<1,0>$. Define $f:(0,2\pi)\to Y$ by $f(\theta)=<\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)>$. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

To understand the above example , I need to know the open sets of $Y$. I find the open sets of $Y$ by imagining bending the disconnected circle into a straight line. The open set on straight line is just like the open set on the circle. But this is an intrinsic image. How to know that my thought of the open sets of $Y$ is the same as the definition of relativized usual topology?

For any other 'curve' on $\mathbb R^2$ which also has a relativized usual topology, can I imagine the open sets in the same way, by bending the curve into straight line? How about for the 'closed curve' such as a complete circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of the relative topology on $Y \subseteq X$, a set $A \subseteq Y$ is open (in $Y$) if and only if $A = C \cap X$ for some open $C \subset X$ (that is, $C$ is open in $X$).  Thus, there is no 'bending' necessary.  In your example, an arc of the circle (without its endpoints) is open in $Y$ because it is possible to find a union of open disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that cover the open arc.  This definition helps to see that in the case of $Y = S^1$ (the entire cirle), the basic open sets are again arcs without endpoints.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand what you are talking about, but this is just the case for a circle. If there is an arbitrary curve, how to prove an arbitrary 'arc' is open, meaning that how can you guarantee you can find an open disc which union with the curve is the arc?

Comment: For an arbitrary curve, the definition remains the same.  If you can cover a piece of the curve with open disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then that piece of the curve is open in the subspace topology.

Comment: And to answer the question 'how can you guarantee you can find an open disc....', there are two points to make:  Often you need more than one open disk (hence the plural disks and the word 'union'); secondly, if it is impossible to find a union of open disks that covers a particular subset of your curve, then that subset is not open, by definition of relative topology.

Answer (score 0):

For $f$ to be a homeomorphism what you need to know is that $f(A)$ is open iff $A$ is, when $A\subseteq (0,2\pi)$.

"Only if" is easy enough; since $f$ is a bijection, that's just the topological definition of $f$ being continuous, and $f$ is clearly continuous.

Conversely, suppose that $A$ is open. Then $A$ is a (possibly infinite) union of *open intervals* in $(0,2\pi)$. The image of each of these intervals is easy to understand -- it's just an open-ended arc -- and it is simple to find an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that intersects $Y$ exactly in that arc. So $f(I)$ is open when $I$ is an open interval. Since $f(A)$ is a (possibly infinite) union of such intervals, it too is open, as required.

Seeing that this is always the case *in general*, for an arbitrary continuous injective curve $(a,b)\to \mathbb R^2$, is surprisingly tricky. It's quite involved to prove that the curve cannot be too wild for the image of an open interval to be open.